# Need a full response in JSON/String from payu money Android. Getting Only PaymentId

Tags: android, payumoney

I am using WebView client for payu money in Android, below is my source code for the same. In success I am getting only paymentId but I need other info like  (payment status, payment mode etc) please check the below code and suggest me how can I get it.

public class PayMentGateWay extends Activity {

```
private ArrayList<String> post_val = new ArrayList<String>();
private String post_Data="";
WebView webView ;
final Activity activity = this;
private String tag = "PayMentGateWay";
private String hash,hashSequence;
ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

String merchant_key = "SHja8Z05";
String salt="0tR0sybux9";
String action1 ="";
String base_url="https://secure.payu.in";//
int error=0;
String hashString="";
Map<String,String> params;
String txnid ="";
String SUCCESS_URL = "https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/success.php" ; 
String FAILED_URL = "https://www.payumoney.com/mobileapp/payumoney/failure.php" ;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
static String getFirstName, getNumber, getEmailAddress, getRechargeAmt;
ProgressDialog pDialog ;

@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    webView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webView);
    Intent oIntent  = getIntent();
    getFirstName    = oIntent.getExtras().getString("FIRST_NAME");
    getNumber       = oIntent.getExtras().getString("PHONE_NUMBER");
    getEmailAddress = oIntent.getExtras().getString("EMAIL_ADDRESS");
    getRechargeAmt  = oIntent.getExtras().getString("RECHARGE_AMT");
    //post_val = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("post_val");
    //Log.d(tag, "post_val: "+post_val);
    params= new HashMap<String,String>();
    params.put("key", merchant_key);
    params.put("amount", getRechargeAmt);
    params.put("firstname", getFirstName);
    params.put("email", getEmailAddress);
    params.put("phone", getNumber);
    params.put("productinfo", "Recharge Wallet");
    params.put("surl", SUCCESS_URL);
    params.put("furl", FAILED_URL);
    params.put("service_provider", "payu_paisa");
    params.put("lastname", "");
    params.put("address1", "");
    params.put("address2", "");
    params.put("city", "");
    params.put("state", "");
    params.put("country", "");
    params.put("zipcode", "");
    params.put("udf1", "");
    params.put("udf2", "");
    params.put("udf3", "");
    params.put("udf4", "");
    params.put("udf5", "");
    params.put("pg", "");

    /*for(int i = 0;i<post_val.size();){
        params.put(post_val.get(i), post_val.get(i+1));
    i+=2;
    }*/
    if(empty(params.get("txnid"))){
        Random rand = new Random();
        String rndm = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt())+(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        txnid=hashCal("SHA-256",rndm).substring(0,20);
        params.put("txnid", txnid);
    }
    else
        txnid=params.get("txnid");
    //String udf2 = txnid;
    String txn="abcd";
    hash="";
    String hashSequence = "key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5|udf6|udf7|udf8|udf9|udf10";
    if(empty(params.get("hash")) && params.size()>0)
    {
        if( empty(params.get("key"))
                || empty(params.get("txnid"))
                || empty(params.get("amount"))
                || empty(params.get("firstname"))
                || empty(params.get("email"))
                || empty(params.get("phone"))
                || empty(params.get("productinfo"))
                || empty(params.get("surl"))
                || empty(params.get("furl"))
                || empty(params.get("service_provider"))

                ){
            error=1;
        }
        else{
            String[] hashVarSeq=hashSequence.split("\\|");

            for(String part : hashVarSeq)
            {
                hashString= (empty(params.get(part)))?hashString.concat(""):hashString.concat(params.get(part));
                hashString=hashString.concat("|");
            }
            hashString=hashString.concat(salt);


            hash=hashCal("SHA-512",hashString);
            action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
        }
    }
    else if(!empty(params.get("hash")))
    {
        hash=params.get("hash");
        action1=base_url.concat("/_payment");
    }

    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(){

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //make sure dialog is showing
            if (!progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

    });


    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);

    //webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(getApplicationContext()), "PayUMoney");
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(), "PayUMoney");
    Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapParams.put("key",merchant_key);
    mapParams.put("hash",PayMentGateWay.this.hash);
    mapParams.put("txnid",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"));
    Log.d(tag, "txnid: "+PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("txnid"));
    mapParams.put("service_provider","payu_paisa");

    mapParams.put("amount",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("amount"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("amount"));
    mapParams.put("firstname",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("firstname"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("firstname"));
    mapParams.put("email",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("email"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("email"));
    mapParams.put("phone",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("phone"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("phone"));

    mapParams.put("productinfo",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("productinfo"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("productinfo"));
    mapParams.put("surl",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("surl"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("surl"));
    mapParams.put("furl",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("furl"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("furl"));
    mapParams.put("lastname",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("lastname"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("lastname"));

    mapParams.put("address1",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address1"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address1"));
    mapParams.put("address2",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address2"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("address2"));
    mapParams.put("city",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("city"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("city"));
    mapParams.put("state",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("state"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("state"));

    mapParams.put("country",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("country"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("country"));
    mapParams.put("zipcode",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("zipcode"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("zipcode"));
    mapParams.put("udf1",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf1"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf1"));
    mapParams.put("udf2",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf2"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf2"));

    mapParams.put("udf3",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf3"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf3"));
    mapParams.put("udf4",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf4"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf4"));
    mapParams.put("udf5",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf5"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("udf5"));
    mapParams.put("pg",(empty(PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"))) ? "" : PayMentGateWay.this.params.get("pg"));
    webview_ClientPost(webView, action1, mapParams.entrySet());

}

private final class PayUJavaScriptInterface {

    PayUJavaScriptInterface() {
    }

    /**
     * This is not called on the UI thread. Post a runnable to invoke
     * loadUrl on the UI thread.
     */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mHandler = null;
                  /*Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.putExtra(Constants.RESULT, "success");
                 intent.putExtra(Constants.PAYMENT_ID, paymentId);
                 setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                 finish();*/
                // new PostRechargeData().execute();
                Intent intent=new Intent(PayMentGateWay.this,MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("test",getFirstName);
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully payment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void failure(final String id, String error) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //cancelPayment();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cancel payment" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void failure() {
        failure("");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void failure(final String params) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                  /*Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.putExtra(Constants.RESULT, params);
                 setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
                 finish();*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed payment" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}


public void webview_ClientPost(WebView webView, String url, Collection< Map.Entry<String, String>> postData){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("<html><head></head>");
    sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
    sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
        sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
    }
    sb.append("</form></body></html>");
    Log.d(tag, "webview_ClientPost called");

    //setup and load the progress bar
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
    webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
}


public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler = null;
            //  new PostRechargeData().execute();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully payment\n redirect from Success Function" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}


public boolean empty(String s)
{
    if(s== null || s.trim().equals(""))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public String hashCal(String type,String str){
    byte[] hashseq=str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try{
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashseq);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();



        for (int i=0;i<messageDigest.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(hex);
        }

    }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae){ }

    return hexString.toString();


}

//String SUCCESS_URL = "https://pay.in/sccussful" ; // failed
//String FAILED_URL = "https://pay.in/failed" ;
//override the override loading method for the webview client
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

     /*if(url.contains("response.php") || url.equalsIgnoreCase(SUCCESS_URL)){

      new PostRechargeData().execute();

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully payment\n redirect from webview" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return false;
     }else  */if(url.startsWith("http")){
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),url ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressDialog.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            System.out.println("myresult "+url);
            //return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

/******************************************* send record to back end ******************************************/
/*class PostRechargeData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PayMentGateWay.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        String strStatus = null;
        ProfileSessionManager ProSessionManager = new ProfileSessionManager(PayMentGateWay.this);

        String getUserid   = ProSessionManager.getSpeculatorId();
        String getSpeculationId  = "0";
        String rechargeAmt = getRechargeAmt;
        String postAction = "1";
        //http://speculometer.com/webService/stockApp/speculationMoneyreports.php?
        //access_token=ISOFTINCstockAppCheckDevelop&speculator=1&speculation=&amount=1000&action=1
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String upLoadServerUri = ServiceList.payment_money_url+"speculator="+getUserid+"&speculation="+getSpeculationId+"&amount="+rechargeAmt+"&action="+postAction;

        try{
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(upLoadServerUri, ServiceHandler.POST);
            JSONObject jsonObj  = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            JSONObject jobjDoc = jsonObj.optJSONObject("document");
            JSONObject jobjRes = jobjDoc.optJSONObject("response");

            strStatus   = jobjRes.getString("status");
            //strMessage  = jobjRes.getString("message");
            String strUserId = jobjRes.getString("user_id");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return strStatus;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final String strStatus)
    {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if(strStatus != null && strStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your recharge amount not added in wallet." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(strStatus != null && strStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your recharge amount added in wallet." ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}*/

/******************************************* closed send record to back end ************************************/
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have also faced the same issue. when contacted them they said on free version they only returns "paymentId", for rest of the fields you have to pay them. for further information about this please email your queries to "techsupport@payumoney.com"

Comment: I have contacted them. Got no response. I am using **LIVE** credentials as well. But getting only two parameters, **result** and **paymentId** @Nilabja

Comment: try mailing `techsupport@payumoney.com` @Maulik Dodia